# Oracle 11g - Join data from multiple rows with m to n relation table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have maybe simple problem but I still can't figure out how make things working.

I have three tables with these important fields:

1. **Rule** - RuleOID
2. **RuleToModificationReason** - RuleOID, MdfnReasonOID
3. **ModificationReason** - MdfnReasonOID, MdfnTyp (CREATION or DELETION), MdfnDetail

And f.e. I have this data:

1. **Rule** - RuleOID = 1
2. **RuleToModificationReason**

   - RuleOID = 1, MdfnReasonOID = 1
   - RuleOID = 1, MdfnReasonOID = 2
3. **ModificationReason**

   - MdfnReasonOID = 1, MdfnTyp = 'CREATION', MdfnDetail = 'Creation detail'
   - MdfnReasonOID = 2, MdfnTyp = 'DELETION', MdfnDetail = 'Deletion detail'

I want to have output on one row for creation and deletion with rule oid.

f.e. : RuleOID, Creation detail, Deletion detail.

I am able to load it in two rows like:

1. RuleOID, Creation detail, NULL
2. RuleOID, NULL , Deletion detail.

Creation and deletion reason can be null.

Is it even possible?

Comment: Are `CREATION` and `DELETION` the only possible values for `MdfnTyp`?  If it's true that the possible values for MdfnType are fixed, then the query is doable w/ subqueries in select fields.

Comment: yes, only `CREATION` and `DELETION` are possible.

Comment: Did this get answered?  Any outstanding questions?

Answer (score 0):

If you're certain that there will always be at *most* one creation-detail for a given rule, and at *most* one deletion-detail for a given rule, then you can use subqueries:

```
SELECT Rule.RuleOID,
       ( SELECT MdfnDetail
           FROM ModificationReason
          WHERE MdfnType = 'CREATION'
            AND MdfnReasonOID IN
                 ( SELECT MdfnReasonOID
                     FROM RuleToModificationReason
                    WHERE RuleOID = Rule.RuleOID
                 )
       ) AS CreationReason,
       ( SELECT MdfnDetail
           FROM ModificationReason
          WHERE MdfnType = 'DELETION'
            AND MdfnReasonOID IN
                 ( SELECT MdfnReasonOID
                     FROM RuleToModificationReason
                    WHERE RuleOID = Rule.RuleOID
                 )
       ) AS DeletionReason
  FROM Rule
;
```

(It's also possible to accomplish this just with `JOIN`s, but that's a lot trickier.)

Comment: No, there is no at most one creation-detail and at most one deletion detail :(

Comment: @JiříVlašimský: Then how do you know which creation-detail and which deletion-detail should show up in the same row?

Answer (score 0):

Will it work for you?

```
SELECT a.RuleOID, 
CASE
  WHEN b.MdfnTyp = 'CREATION' THEN b.MdfnDetail
  ELSE NULL -- can omit, case has default "else null"
END AS creation_detail,
CASE
  WHEN b.MdfnTyp = 'DELETION' THEN b.MdfnDetail
  ELSE NULL -- can omit, case has default "else null"
END AS deletion_detail

RuleToModificationReason a
INNER JOIN ModificationReason b ON (a.MdfnReasonOID = b.MdfnReasonOID)
```

Note : Rule table skipped by purpose (assuming referential integrity is enforced by constraints) because you don't use any fields from that table

Comment: unfotunatelly, I use more fields from the Rule table. But thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

```
select crtr.RuleOID RuleOID, crt.MdfnDetail Creation_detail, dlt.MdfnDetail Deletion_detail
from ModificationReason crt, ModificationReason dlt, RuleToModificationReason crtr, RuleToModificationReason dltr
where crt.MdfnTyp = 'CREATION' and dlt.MdfnTyp = 'DELETION'
and crt.MdfnReasonOID = crtr.MdfnReasonOID
and dlt.MdfnReasonOID = dltr.MdfnReasonOID
and crtr.RuleOID = dltr.RuleOID
```

(couldn't check it)

Comment: this won't work where there is no creation/deletion reason for the rule ;)